# Insufficient tokens for quota 'AnalyticsDefaultGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 'analyticsreporting.googleapis.com' for consumer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, google-api

I am using `async.eachOfSeries` over 300+ array and requesting some of GA apis , It woorks fine but sometimes I am getting error ..

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Insufficient tokens for quota

> 'AnalyticsDefaultGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service
>   'analyticsreporting.googleapis.com' for consumer
>   'project_number:79317181646'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas)

> In the API Console, there is a similar quota referred to as Requests per 100 seconds per user. By default, it is set to `100 requests per 100 seconds per user` and can be adjusted to a maximum value of 1,000. But the number of requests to the API is restricted to a maximum of 10 requests per second per user.

This error is flood protection.  You can only send 100 requests a second per user.  User is denoted by your ip address.  You need to slow down.

Note: Google is not perfect you can send 99 requests in one second and then try and wait 90 seconds and try again it may or may not work.  Just slow down and try again.

Comment: but I am using 3 api in 3 seconds ... but yes after slowing more it is working

Comment: The quota is the same for all the Google Analytics APIs.

Comment: you may want to consider implementing [backoff](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors#backoff)

Comment: @DalmTo yes after slowing down it is working https://stackoverflow.com/a/50945781/7129694

Answer (score 0):

After setting settimeout it seems working

```
function getBeautyrestReport(cb){
    apiGA.totalSiteVisitor(1,START_DATE,END_DATE,(error,data)=>{
        if(error) mail.sendError(error);
        let pageView = data['pageView']||0;
        let bounceRate = data['bounceRate']||0;
        setTimeout(() => {
            cb(pageView,bounceRate);
           }, 500);
    });
}
```